# Return value when no record exists on join, oracle

Tags: sql

I have simple scenario but struggling at it:

Say I have following 2 tables:

```
tableA
Acol1 Acol2 Acol3       
1       2     3 

tableB
Bcol1 Bcol2 Bcol3   
1       2    true
```

A query:

```
select tabB.Bcol3 from tableA tabA, tableB tabB
where
tabA.Acol1 = tabB.Bcol1
and tabB.Bcol2 = 1
and tabA.Acol1 = 1;
```

I want my query to return 'false' value since no record exists for this query.

P.S: I cannot user aggregate functions because actually this scenario is part of a larger query with around 15 joins and multiple columns.

So following solution is out of context:

```
   select decode(max(tabB.Bcol3), null, 'FALSE', 'TRUE') from tableA tabA, tableB tabB
    where
    tabA.Acol1 = tabB.Bcol1
    and tabB.Bcol2 = 1
    and tabA.Acol1 = 1;
```

i tried left and right outer joins but in vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` with [`COALESCE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm):

```
select coalesce(tabB.Bcol3, false)
from tableA tabA
left join tableB tabB on tabA.Acol1 = tabB.Bcol2
    and tabB.Bcol2 = 1
where tabA.Acol1 = 1;
```

`COALESCE()` returns the first non-null value. When the join fails to find a match, the columns of tableB will be null - that's when the default value of `false` will be returned.

It seems a little-known fact that join conditions may include non-key conditions. By including the extra condition on tabkeB in the join condition, the left join is still effective in returning a row for tableA. If left in the where clause, no row would be returned be ause the where clause is d listed *after* the join is made and would fail because a null is not going to equal 1.

Comment: Thx, But I just relaized a little mistake In my question the join is sucessfull, but the record does not exist on the filter (where clause).
i.e. Join is like :  tabA.Acol1 = tabB.Bcol1

Comment: Oops. I fixed it. Just move the condition on rableb from the whete ckause into the join clause. Try it now.

Comment: Thx: It works well (not sure why i did not try it) :)

I inherently prefer the (+) operator to the ansi representation, query looks cleaner that way (especially the larger ones). I know people will frown on me for saying that. nevertheless
The following query would be the equivalent of the above query you gave right?:

select coalesce(tabB.Bcol3, false)
from tableA tabA, tableB tabB where tabA.Acol1 = tabB.Bcol2 (+)
    and tabB.Bcol2 (+) = 1
and tabA.Acol1 = 1;

Comment: No, not the same. The old fashioned join (pre 1996) is inherently an *inner* join, with which you don't get your default value when a row isn't found in tableb. A .*left* join is an *outer* join